# Is there any method to make the size random to the instanced objects created via Animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes, instances

I made the instances from a collection (of 4 objects) with the help of Animation nodes. I would like to change the sizes of each objects randomly. Now it seems all uniform and if i try to change the scale its all scaling equally. Any method to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use combination of `Random Number` and `Vector from Value` node.

[image]

Random scaled objects from a collection:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But its not working for me.I am using a collection for instancing. I used "Collection Info" and "Copy Object Data" nodes to create this instancing with collection.

Comment: @ArunNura It should work. Can you show your full node tree?

Comment: Please have a look : https://ibb.co/F6vjHH6

Comment: @ArunNura It looks like `Object Matrix Output` node is overriding `Object Transforms output` node. You probably only need one not both.

Comment: @ArunNura Updated my answer

Comment: is it possible to create the instancing with any one of the two nodes you mentioned?

Comment: @ArunNura Yes look at my second screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Use a Random Vector node if you want non uniform scale. Don't forget to click on the icon on the right of the *node seed* field to "Vectorize" the node.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. But its not Not working for me.Could you please have a look on the node tree :https://ibb.co/F6vjHH6